# ffmpeg avcodec_get_frame_defaults was declared deprecated

Tags: function, audio, ffmpeg

To make ffmpeg simple player

I refer to ffmpeg sample code
(https://github.com/phamquy/FFmpeg-tutorial-samples/blob/master/tutorial03.c)

In window 7 with visual studio 12

First I made cmd-project, all link, and complie is OK

But when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in vs12

```
**1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp (141): error C4996: 'avcodec_get_frame_defaults': was declared deprecated
   Failed | ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj [Debug|x64]**
```

What happen with me?

I download latest ffmpeg DLL again, but noting is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc don't treat deprecation warnings as errors. You can delete 'attribute_deprecated' from avcodec.h or change your compiler behaviour.

Comment: thanks i just add #pragma warning(disable:4996) and sloved

Answer (score 5):

The comment around the function declaration for `avcodec_get_frame_defaults` says that you should use `av_frame_unref` and the code seems to be doing just that:

```
void avcodec_get_frame_defaults(AVFrame *frame)
{
#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_MAJOR >= 55
     // extended_data should explicitly be freed when needed, this code is unsafe currently
     // also this is not compatible to the <55 ABI/API
    if (frame->extended_data != frame->data && 0)
        av_freep(&frame->extended_data);
#endif

    memset(frame, 0, sizeof(AVFrame));
    av_frame_unref(frame);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see the [official post](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/APIchanges#L1097) from Ffmpeg github :

```
2013-12-11 - 29c83d2 / b9fb59d,409a143 / 9431356,44967ab / d7b3ee9 - lavc 55.45.101 / 55.28.1 - avcodec.h
  av_frame_alloc(), av_frame_unref() and av_frame_free() now can and should be
  used instead of avcodec_alloc_frame(), avcodec_get_frame_defaults() and
  avcodec_free_frame() respectively. The latter three functions are deprecated.
```